# dry contact control relay - Am I on the right path

Tags: solid-state-relay

[image]Need help understanding a dry contact control relay.

My goal is to cut power to an electronics module ( 100 mA max ) with a contact closure input to the relay.  By "contact closure" I mean simply the equivalent of mechanical toggle switch closing.

I would need a NC output on the relay to maintain power to the electronics module until the contact closure occurs on the input to the dry contact control relay.

Am I correct that a "dry contact control relay" would accomplish this?

Comment: I have difficulties understanding your problem. I recommend adding a schematic, even if you don't know your components yet. If so, use boxes instead and describe what they should do.

Comment: is there any reason why you refer to "dry contact control relay"? are you taking about a mechanical relay?

Comment: My objective is to turn off power to an electronics module based on a contact closure.  It is my understanding that a "dry contact control relay" does exactly this.  Instead of triggering a conventional relay with a small electrical feed, I want to trigger a relay with a contact closure, non-powered.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a dry contact relay is will do what you need.  It must be either normally closed or you can use one with a double throw contact arrangement.

Based only on what you've revealed about the load so far, there no way to advise on sizing and selecting the type of contact.  You might comment if the voltage you're switching to the load is ac or D.C.  and what that voltage is.  Also, is the load resistive, inductive, or an incandescent lamp?

Comment: Thank you!  I am switching 12v DC.  I will need to dig into what you mean by your sentence "It must be either normally closed or you can use one with a double throw contact arrangement" because my dry contact input will be normally open.

I should be OK sizing the component but am happy to share more details too.  The 12v DC operates an off-the-shelf motion sensor electronics module.

Comment: OP, look up Form B and Form C contact arrangement.   One of those should work for you to break the circuit when energized.  I only mention Form C as an alternative if you can't find the Form B (NC).  Also check the contact current rating for D.C. when choosing the relay.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I appreciate the insight and support.